# Convertion from ESRI Shapefile into OS VectorMap Local GML

Tags: xml, esri, shapefile, vml, gml

I have to create a program for converting `ESRI Shapefiles` into `OS VectorMap Local GMLs`. I'm looking for some information for my problem... I tried to use documentation from both sites:

- [ESRI Shapefile documentation](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf)
- [OS VectorMap Local documentation](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/docs/user-guides/os-vectormap-local-gml-user-guide.pdf)

I use `ESRI Shapefile Reader library` and it works fine. I can read my `*.shp` files. The problem is I don't know where I should get `featureCode` from...

```
  <osgb:lineMember>
    <osgb:Line fid="ID_864">
      <osgb:featureCode>15600</osgb:featureCode>
      <osgb:featureDescription>Water Feature</osgb:featureDescription>
      <osgb:polyline>
        <gml:LineString srsName="osgb:BNG">
          <gml:coordinates>405513.50,408701.00 405514.01,408707.15 405514.50,408711.50</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:LineString>
      </osgb:polyline>
    </osgb:Line>
  </osgb:lineMember>
```

`ESRI Shapefiles` contain only coordinates, so I don't know what its feature code is...

The 2nd thing is `<osgb:textMember>` tag. WTF is a `textMember`? Which one shape type in `ESRI Shapefile`?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**[edit]**
Or maybe you know some library/program for doing convertion like this? It'd be a great solution aswell:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your conversion question is easy enough - GDAL can convert from shp -> VML, using [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html). See the comments on [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29169/quantim-gis-python-script-to-convert-shapefile-to-gml) for syntax.

Comment: From https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/os-vectormap-local/index.html, it says "Formats: Vector GML 2.1.2". Everything else I can find on Google suggests the same thing. What are you trying to do with your GML (or VML GML)?

Comment: Strange, because I tried to use `ogr2ogr` and the output is completely different as [here](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/docs/user-guides/os-vectormap-local-gml-user-guide.pdf). I need this convertion in my app. It's a worker app, which should return `VML GML` files for another app.